# Electromagnetic Variational Principle and Concentration of Optical energy

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, eigenvalue

While reading a book on photonic crystals, I came across the Electromagnetic Variational Principle. If   the electric and magnetic fields are represented by the real part of
$$\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r}, t)=\mathbf{H}(\mathbf{r}) e^{-i \omega t} ,\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t)=\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) e^{-i \omega t} $$

the lowest frequency eigen mode profile is $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)$ which minimises the functional

\begin{aligned}
U_{f}(\mathbf{H}) &=\frac{(\nabla \times \mathbf{E}, \nabla \times \mathbf{E})}{(\mathbf{E}, \varepsilon(\mathbf{r}) \mathbf{E})} \\
&=\frac{\int d^{3} \mathbf{r}|\nabla \times \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})|^{2}}{\int d^{3} \mathbf{r} \varepsilon(\mathbf{r})|\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})|^{2}}
\end{aligned}

and higher eigenmodes minimise $U_f(\mathbf{H})$ given they are orthogonal to the lower eigenmodes. The text then mentions that to minimise $U_f(\mathbf{H})$, the electric field should be concentrated in regions of high $\varepsilon(\mathbf{r})$ (hence increasing the denominator). This would mean that if I have a periodic, lossless, non-dispersive and sourceless dielectric stack with layers of different $\varepsilon$, the mode $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ would have higher values in the layer with higher $\varepsilon$ ( image below ). We can superpose these eigenmodes to get an arbitrary wave propogating through the structure.
[image]
**Question**

In a homogenous layer of the dielectric with continuous translational symmetry, the mode profile $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$ can be written as a plane wave $e^{i\mathbf{k}.\mathbf{r}}$, which gives $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}) e^{-i \omega t} = e^{i\mathbf{k}.\mathbf{r}-i \omega t}$, a travelling wave.

That would mean that the wave profile "moves" through the dielectric layers and each point within a layer should have the same "amplitude" of the electric field and hence the electric field energy.

In that case , what does the mode profile in the above image represent? Given that the profile will move with time, doesn't every layer in dielectric stack "get" the same electric field energy? The only way this makes sense to me is that even within a specific layer, the amplitude of $\mathbf{E}$ changes, which is what the image represents. But I can't reconcile it with the idea that a wave propogating in a homogeneous ( and source free ) medium shouldn't change its amplitude.

Another needed clarification was the meaning of $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r})$. Does it just represent the direction and amplitude of the electric field vector at point at $\mathbf{r}$ that oscillates in time at frequency $w$?